# A problem with the behaviour of scanf when data type is unsigned char

Tags: c, scanf, unsigned-char

So I have no idea why this behavior is observed:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned char c;
    char d;
    scanf("%hhu", &d);
    printf("%c\n", d);

    return 0;
}
```

If I remember correctly `%hhu` is for `unsigned char`. If I input almost any character like `a`, or `b` the answer is nothing and `d` gets the value `0`. But if I input `97` then `d` prints the value `a` (so ASCII is converted to char). This clearly not the case when the data type is `char`. I can just input the character directly and it is stored.

Also in the slight modification of this code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned char c;
    char d;
    int g;
    scanf("%hhu", &d);
    printf("%c\n", d);
    scanf("%d", &g);
    printf("%d is g\n", g);

    return 0;
}
```

If I give first input as a character like `w` or `a` then it just skips the second `scanf`, but if the input is a number then it works normally.

Comment: `a` is not a valid input for `%hhu`, so `scanf` returns an error. Check the value returned by `scanf`.

Comment: Re "*This is two different questions*", No, just two examples of providing bad data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a` is not a valid input for `%hhu`. An integer (in the Math sense) is expected. If we add error checking (code below), we get:

```
$ gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic a.c -o a && ./a
a
Number of assigned variables: 0
Can't read: Invalid input
```

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    unsigned char c;

    int rv = scanf("%hhu", &c);
    if (rv == EOF) {
       if (ferror(stdin)) {
          perror("Can't read");
       } else {
          fprintf(stderr, "Can't read: Premature EOF\n");
       }

       exit(1);
    }

    printf("Number of assigned variables: %d\n", rv);

    if (rv < 1) {
       fprintf(stderr, "Can't read: Invalid input\n");
       exit(1);
    }

    printf("%hhu\n", c);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Invalid input stays in the handle's buffer to be obtained by future reads. So an error in a early `scanf` can cause later `scanf` to fail.

If you wish to proceed after an error, you could simply read until you get a LF to clear any "junk" in the buffer.

```
void read_stdin_to_eol(void) {
   while (1) {
      int ch = getchar();
      if (ch == '\n' || ch == EOF)
         return ch;
   }
}
```

Comment: For the understanding of scanf which talks about 'handle's buffer' like you explained, can I get some sources or pointers?

Comment: It just means the invalid input is not absorbed. Future reads will start at the character that caused the error rather than the one after it. It's not clear from the man page on my system that this happens.

Answer (score 5):

You are correct that the `%hhu` format specifier expects an `unsigned char*` argument. However, the `u` part of the format dictates that the input be interpreted as a **decimal integer**. To input the data as an (unprocessed) character, you should use the `%c` format specifier.

Answer (score 3):

Format specifier `%u` is for reading decimal integer and `%hhu` is `%u` with length modifier added.

To read one character to `char` variable, use specifier `%c`.

Answer (score 3):

> If I input almost any character like 'a', or 'b' the answer is nothing and d gets the value 0. But if I input 97 then d prints the value a. (so ASCII is converted to char) This clearly not the case when the data type is char.

What `scanf` does is not related to the type but to the format specifier you use (which in turn defines what types are expected in the arguments).

When you use `%hhu`, the input is read as a signed decimal *integer*, parsed as `strtoul` would, and stored in an `unsigned char`. This is why `97` is read correctly.

Further, in both examples you should take into account the return value to know whether there was any failure. That way you will be able to detect errors and do whatever is required, like asking the user again.

Answer (score 2):

> If I remember correctly `%hhu` is for `unsigned char`. If I input almost any character like 'a', or 'b' the answer is nothing and d gets the value 0.

`"%hhu"` expects input text to be numeric like `"123"`.  Then the value of 123  is save in `d`.  `d` did not *get* the value of 0. `d` was not changed by the `scanf("%hhu", &d);` as input was invalid.

If you want to read a character into an `unsigned char`

```
unsigned char d;
if (scanf("%c", &d) == 1) Success();
```

If you want to read a numeric text into an `unsigned char`

```
unsigned char d;
if (scanf("%hhu", &d) == 1) Success();
```

In all cases, test the return value of `scanf()`.

---

> If I give first input as a character like 'w' or 'a' then it just skips the second scanf, but if the input is a number then it works normally.

When `scanf()` fails to convert input text per the provided specifiers, scanning stops and the offending text *remains* in `stdin`.

A common code idiom is to read remaining input and toss it until `'\n'`.

```
int ch;
while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n') && ch !- EOF) {
  ;
}
```